# git grep showing absolute paths

Tags: git, bash, grep

I would like to use git grep from outside the repository, for example editing a file in vim. This works:

```
git -C /path/to/gitrepo/ grep 'my search'
```

The problem is that the results show relative path from `/path/to/gitrepo`. So, I cannot open them directly.

Is there any way to generate the full file path to the matches? From `git` would be great, but a hacky solution to prepend and build the absolute path will do too.

Comment: The usual output is just one line per match (though this does depend on options). In this case, a simple `git -C $path grep pattern | sed s,^,$path,` does the trick (assuming no "," in paths).

Comment: This does it for the one line per match. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual output is just one line per match (though this does depend on options). In this case, a simple `git -C $path grep pattern | sed s,^,$path,` does the trick (assuming no "," in paths).
                    – torek

Answer (score 1):

```
[alias]
        egrep = "!f1() { git grep --line-number \"$1\" | sed \"s,^,$PWD/,g\"  | sed \"s/^\\(.*:[0-9]\\{1,10\\}\\):/\\1 /g\" ; }; f1"
```

This is my git alias config.
Usage: git egrep 'my search' .
This would give you filenames with fullpath and line number.